# Question regarding Array.From input parameters ( array, iterable) syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, javascript-objects

I have below statement and it gives correct result but I do not know how `{length:5},(_,index)` is an array or iterable. Please help me to understand.

```js
console.log(Array.from({length:5},(_,index) => console.log(index)));

Result
0
1
2
3
4
```

Array.From() documentation says https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

> The Array.from() static method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an iterable or array-like object.

Regards